# getSize() of S3ObjectSummary

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to listing the object from a given S3 prefix to get the file size for each objects.

Does the `S3ObjectSummary#getSize()` represents the real unencrypted content length when I use server side encryption (sse) or client size encryption (cse)?

(I guess `S3ObjectSummary#getSize()` is not the real unencrypted content length under cse, but not sure about sse).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`getSize()` will return the real decrypted object size when using SSE-S3.